# Laravel custom inflection

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a custom inflection to Laravel. In Rails this wasn't that hard to do, but I cannot seem to find an answer on how to do it in Laravel.

How do I add my own inflection to Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably doing:

```
Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer::$irregular['subscribe'] = 'subscribes';
```

Best place to load it is a Service Provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer;

class PluralizationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        Pluralizer::$irregular['octopus'] = 'octopi';
    }

}
```

And load it in your app/config/app.php:

```
'App\Providers\PluralizationServiceProvider',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far! Seems to be what I'm looking for. Could you please tell me what the best place is to add this line of code?

Comment: Nowadays? In a pluralization service provider, and load it in your app/config/app.php.

Answer (score 2):

This no longer works for current Laravel. Now you have to write:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;

class PluralizationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        Inflector::rules('plural', ['irregular' => ['octopus' => 'octopi']]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also necessary add the providers folder to your composer autoload.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "app/providers"
    ]
},
```